# Regex that match everything except the list of strings

Tags: javascript, regex

I need regex that match Scheme identifier that will terminate if it find any of the not allowed strings.

I have code like this:

```
function make_tokens_re() {
    var tokens = specials.names()
        .sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length || a.localeCompare(b))
        .map(escape_regex).join('|');
    return new RegExp(`(#\\\\(?:x[0-9a-f]+|${character_symbols}|[\\s\\S])|#f|#t|#;|(?:${num_stre})(?=$|[\\n\\s()[\\]])|\\[|\\]|\\(|\\)|\\|[^|]+\\||;.*|(?:#[ei])?${float_stre}(?=$|[\\n\\s()[\\]])|\\n|\\.{2,}|(?!#:|'#[ft])(?:${tokens})|[^(\\s)[\\]]+)`, 'gim');
}
```

**NOTE:** This regex is used in `String::split`.

What I need to change `[^(\\s)[\\]]+` to also don't match `tokens`, special character list (default `` ` `` `'` `,` `,@` there can be more and longer, they can be added by the user) they should be acting as separators and end the symbol.

I've tried this:

```
/.+(?!\)|\(|\[|\]|`|'|,@|,)/
```

but it match `xxxx,`, I think what I need is and operator not or.

I've also tried this:

```
/.*(?!,).(?!,@)./
```

but when tweaking it only work with single string either `,@` or `,`.

Is something like this possible with Regular expressions?

**EDIT:**

This almost works:

```
/.*(?=,@|,)/
```

the problem is when I'm adding or `|$` it match including the `,@` or `,`.

Comment: Hey, your regex is very complex, but I would try doing something like NOT(a OR b OR c) `?!( | | | | )`.

Comment: @Deykun you mean `.*(?!(?:,@|,))`? It don't work. PS: My regex is just `[^(\\s)[\\]]+` that also need exception in form of strings. I've added my whole code for context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was two values:

```
`[^(\\s)[\\]]+(?=${tokens})|[^(\\s)[\\]]+`
```

first will match any character that have my tokens

So general solution look like this, if you have list `foo, bar, baz`:

use:

```
/\w+(?=foo|bar|baz)|\w+/
```

it will match any word that in next token have any provided value or just the word without anything.