# Regex that matches everything except given full word

Tags: javascript, regex

This is similar to [javascript regular expression to not match a word](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15508679/387194), but the accepted answer shows a regex that doesn't match if the word is inside the line. I want to match everything except the full word. It will match `"__lambda__"`.

This is also similar to my question [Regex that match everything except the list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63320400/387194) but that one gives a solution with `String::split` and I want to use normal match full string.

For example, it should match everything except `/^lambda$/` I would prefer to have a regex for this, since it will fit my pattern patching function. It should match lambda_ or _lambda and everything else - *except* full "lambda" token.

I've tried this:

```
/^(.(?!lambda))+$/
```

and

```
/^((?!lambda).)+$/
```

this works

```
/^(.*(?<!lambda))$/
```

but I would prefer to not have to use a negative lookbehind if I can avoid it (because of browser support). Also, I have interpreter written in JavaScript that I need this for and I would like to use this in guest language (I will not be able to compile the regex with babel).

Is something like this possible with regex without lookbehind?

**EDIT:**

THIS IS NOT DUPLICATE: I don't want to test if something contains or doesn't contain the word, but if something is not exact word. There are not question on Stack Overflow like that.

Question [Regex: Match word not containing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33159862/387194) has almost as correct an answer as mine, but it's not the full answer to the question. (It would help in finding solution, though.)

Comment: browser support? does anyone really care about IE Safari Opera Mini or Baidu? :D

Comment: @JaromandaX I compile everything to ES5. I prefer to have something that works everywhere.

Comment: This is not duplicate, there are no question that ask about single full word regex, it seems that all have contain. I don't want to test if something contain that is simple my first question linked is just for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the solution based on [How to negate specific word in regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1240365/387194)

```js
var re = /^(?!.*\blambda\b).*$/;

var words = ['lambda', '_lambda', 'lambda_', '_lambda_', 'anything'];
words.forEach(word => {
  console.log({word, match: word.match(re)});
});
```

Comment: would `re = /\blambda\b/` and `words.filter(w => !re.test(w))` work for you?

Comment: @Sundeep as I said in the question I needed single regex, I know that I can negate the result. But what you really want is /^lambda$/ since your regex will return true for "lambda lambda" that is not valid.